# Can i bundle and minify my app folder's js files in MVC Project?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, minify

I have created two script bundles for my jquery js files and bootstrap js files and a content bundle for all css files. What about my js files which i have used in my app and other application folders? Can i do bundle and minify those application's js files using bundle.config of my MVC Project? I am little confused what to bundle and what not to bundle and what project structure to follow ? Any help will be highly appreciated. Does bundle.config automatically does the minification of files?

Answer (score 1):

You can create bundles per view, that include all the css or js for that view. You can bundle all the scripts, except the one that are pulled from cdn. The minification do not happen by default, you need to set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`.

Try to obtain the third-party libraries already minified, and put it on the scripts folder using .min.js suffix. asp will use that files instead of minify the current sources.

```
example:

jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js // this on the bundle
jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js // on optimization mode asp will use this library
```